# Accessing a member of a struct and comparing it with a constant

Tags: assembly, nasm

I have an uninitialized struct:

```
    struc my_struct1
        .a resd
        .b resb
        .c resd
        .d resb
     endstruc
```

Then it gets filled with data:

```
    mov rax, 123
    ;.........

    mov rdi, [my_struct1]
    ;.........

    syscall
```

How then I can compare what values does one of its fields have? In C I'd do this by:

```
if (my_struct1.c == SOME_CONSTANT) {
  //......
}
```

Comment: This little tutorial might give you some inspiration: http://mcs.uwsuper.edu/sb/224/Intro/struct_nasm.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do this pretty much the same way as you would do it in c, no? Just find the address of the field in mystruct and then do a cmp with your constant and check whichever flag you need.

```
cmp [mystruct1+4], YOUR_CONSTANT
jz  .jump_somewhere_if_fields_are_equal
```

You can read a full explanation of how to use a struct properly here, http://mcs.uwsuper.edu/sb/224/Intro/struct_nasm.html

Comment: This is just an idea of what it would look like, not functional code.

Comment: Edited it slightly too look more like intel/nasm

Comment: why 4? can't I access it by its name?

Comment: Just picked 4 as a random offset, like I said this isn't intended to be directly usable code. You should be able to look at your struct layout and see the offset or you can just use whatever tag you have assigned that field.

Comment: I asked:  can't I access it by its name?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to use the tags, since the assembler should calculate the tag offset for you.